# check both if session or null in if code asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session

### how can i check both if session or null in if code asp.net

something like

> if(Session["user"] != null || Session["user"] = null)
>
>      // do something 
>
> else 
>
>      //do something

how can i do this

Comment: Please explain more what you are intending to do.

Comment: I am confused as to what you are trying to achieve here, are you actually wanting a scenario where you do something if a `Session` does or does not exist, but then do something if it does not? The `else` will never happen, because the `if` is always true. Please rephrase your question or reconsider what it is you are actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't make sense

You are missing an = sign, but

```
if(Session["user"] != null || Session["user"] == null)
```

Will always be true, so just skip the if

Did you mean to write something like this:

```
if(Session["user"] != null)
{
  //do something when session is not null
}
else
{
  //do something when session is null
}
```

Comment: yes thanks  if(Session["user"] != null || Session["user"] == null) is what i need  i need to save even if have session or not  thanks for help